# Paginação em página category.php no WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estou tentando ativar a paginação do WordPress em um arquivo category.php de um tema, mas os links de paginação não aparecem. Pelo pouco que eu pesquisei, teria algo a ver com o uso de custom queries, mas eu não compreendi bem o seu uso.

Como eu poderia ativar a paginação (seja nativa ou com o plugin WP PostNavi) no código da minha página, mostrado abaixo?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>  
  <main>
  <div id="content_internas">
    <div id="lista_noticias">
      <h2><span><?php echo strtoupper(single_cat_title( '', false )) ?></span></h2>
      <ul>
          <?php $posts = get_all_posts(null, get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) )); ?>

          <?php foreach($posts as $key => $post): ?>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) {
              if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(460, 300, true)); ?></a>
              <?php } } ?>
          </a>
          <br />
          <span><?php the_time('j F') ?></span>
          <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
          <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <div class="paginacao">
        <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) : ?>
          COM PLUGIN
          <?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
        <?php else : ?>
          SEM PLUGIN
          <div class="maisantigos"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Mais antigos','arclite')) ?></div>
          <div class="maisrecentes"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Mais recentes &raquo;','arclite')) ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <!--<center><a href="#" id="veja_mais">MAIS NOTÍCIAS</a></center>--><br> <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Faltam algumas informações: o plugin wp_pagenavi está ativo e configurado para ser exibido mesmo quando há apenas uma página? Ele simplesmente não é exibido ou apresenta uma mensagem de erro em vez disso? No código que você postou, você vê a mensagem "COM PLUGIN"?

Comment: Por favor, coloque seu código aqui, se o Pastebin sumir a pergunta perde o sentido. Você pode [edit] o post e incluir o código.

Comment: Desculpe pela falta de informações. Na verdade minha intenção era fazer o código de forma redundante, podendo ser usado com ou sem o PageNavi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe a função `get_all_posts()` no WordPress, tente procurar ela: http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/

Provavelmente é alguma função customizada, onde não é configurada a variável global `$wp_query` e por isso não funciona paginação.

Como você quer utilizar o `category.php` o correto é utilizar a query nativa do WordPress.
No caso basta utilizar como:

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main>
<div id="content_internas">
    <div id="lista_noticias">
        <h2><span><?php echo strtoupper(single_cat_title( '', false )) ?></span></h2>
        <ul>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 460, 300, true ) ); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </a>
                <br />
                <span><?php the_time( 'j F' ); ?></span>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <li><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
        <div class="paginacao">
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) : ?>
                COM PLUGIN
                <?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                SEM PLUGIN
                <div class="maisantigos"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Mais antigos','arclite')) ?></div>
                <div class="maisrecentes"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Mais recentes &raquo;','arclite')) ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Você pode encontrar mais detalhes de como trabalhar com o [loop do WordPress aqui](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Nota 1: No seu código você testou se existia a função [`has_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail), note que ela foi implementada no [WordPress 2.9](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.9), que teve sua data de lançamento em 18 de Dezembro de 2009. Em outras palavras, você não precisa nunca testar se existe, ninguém vai estar utilizando um WordPress tão desatualizado assim.

Nota 2: Se você quiser não tem a menor necessidade de utilizar o WP-PagiNavi, pelo menos não desde de 22 de Janeiro de 2007 quando foi lançado o [WordPress 2.1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.1) e junto foi implementada a função [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links).

Comment: Esse carinha que tá falando manja tudo de Wordpress. Um abraço Claudio que me ajudou algumas vezes na comunidade do Facebook.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, Claudio! Sua solução funcionou perfeitamente.